# It is possible to extract Extented Properties using SQL Developer Data Modeler?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using `SQL Developer Data Modeler` in a oracle server. No problem, I can connect to SQL Server, list tables and generate a really good report. But what I need is to extract the `extended properties`  from tables and columns. I'm looking all over the internet but what I found is:

```
MS SQL Server
Support for following objects – database, login, user and roles with their privileges and permissions, default, rule, user-defined type, computed and identity columns, partitioned tables using partition function and partition scheme, primary and secondary XML indexes, triggers on tables and views, stored procedures, indexes on views, synonyms
    Domains can be created as user-defined types
    **Extended properties for each object can be defined and generated in DDL**
    Database and schema controlled generation of DDL
```

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/featurelist-167684.html

From the official manual. But I don't want to generate manually the properties with the software. I  have already all properties of extended properties from almost all tables.

Or can I make a Data Dictionary with my good SQL Server Management Studio? I can only see reports from disk usage, performance metrics and etc.

This is what I have for now:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what your use case is, but you can retrieve them by querying the [`sys.extended_properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/extended-properties-catalog-views-sys-extended-properties) system view.

SSMS doesn't provide a helpful way to view extended properties outside of the individual dialogue window for a single object anyways, so this is probably your best route.

**Neither tool will be able to build you a data dictionary** necessarily, but you can generate a simple one by querying from any tool.

Comment: oh I know. I made a query to extract everything we need, but with `data modeler` we can report a real report. With `Data Modeler` we can create a data dictionary ready to show to our clients. Thats Why the problem. I can do it in Oracle, the report is perfect for it. But for Sql, this is the only flaw we found.

Comment: Like I said, neither tool will build you a data dictionary via MSSQL extended properties.

Comment: No, I don't want a data dictionary via Extended Properties. I have a report, with all tables, all columns, indexes, everything. I just would like to know if there's a way, to , besides what I already have, to add the "Extended Properties" in this report.I've edited my quesrtion. If you see, there are all field I need, but not EXtended Properties. I don't want to fill it in this report ( Inside Data Modeler ). I would like to fill Extended properties and then, just import this report, with that field as "notes" for example.

Comment: Ah, I see now. What are the names of the extended properties? Most tools will key in to them only if they're named "MS_Description"